# Restricting to the case X and Y are affine

Tags: schemes, affine-schemes

I am starting to study schemes and I am struggling with the practice of restricting to the affine case. I explain a little more: generally when we want to build a morphism between two schemes $X$ and $Y$ we reduce to the case in which $X,Y$ are affine, we build the morphism in this case and then we check that this family of maps glue to a global morphism. The problem I am struggling with is to check the maps I built can be glued. Is there any general reason for which such construction always give us glueable maps? An explicit example is the following: given a scheme $X$ let $X_{red}$ be the reduced scheme and let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes, I want to build a morphism of schemes $f_{red} : X_{red}\rightarrow Y_{red}$ such that $ i_Y \circ f_{red} = f \circ i_X$, where $i_X,i_Y$ are the inclusion morphisms. For every $x \in X$ I can find affine open subset $U_x$ of $x$ and $V_{f(x)}$ of $f(x)$ such that $f(U_x) \subseteq V_{f(x)}$, then here $f = Spec(\phi)$ for some morphism of rings $\phi$, and I set $f_{red}$ on this open subset to be the map corresponding to the morphism of rings induced by $\phi$ on the reductions. However I don’t understand why these maps should coincide on the intersections.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Check out exercise 2.12 in Hartshorne, chapter II.

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant or at least I don't understand how to draw some conclusion from it. In the example I provided I built a map on each affine open subset of a covering and I do not see why the book states that these maps glue. My question is whether I am missing something and eventually whether this is true for some general reason. Thank you!

Comment: In Hartshorne page 88, in "step 3" he defines the process of gluing morphisms. 

Now in you specific example, you don't actually need to restrict to the affine case. An almost complete construction for the morphism is given in exercise 2.3, page 79.